# File and Line number indicate my Local computer instead of Server computer

Tags: iis, asmx

I have done my web sevice (asmx web servicec) successfully. And then I deployed in my server pc (Windows Server 2008) with IIS 7 successfully also. I can use from my client app. But some times when my web service shows error, the error indicates the line number of my local computer where I developed the web service. But it sould be the server pc address.

Important thing: sometimes I change small thing in my web service and then I just copy the full project and paste in server pc with correct path. And it runs well but when it comes with error, the error indicate the file name and line number is located in my local pc where I developed the web service. I am using SVN. I could not understand what is the reason to indicate the local pc instead of server pc location while errro shows.

I always use Cleand and Rebuild before copy/paste the project to server pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug information in the PDB file is where this is taken from, and it is generated at compilation time and reflects the location of the source code file at that time. Entirely correct behaviour.

Comment: I am not worried about error, i will handle that. But I am worried about file location when creates error. It shows my local computer location where my project is stored and I worked. But it should be server computer address where the project is deployed. So what is your suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: Why should it be? You don't deploy the source files to the server as well, do you? The information would be meaningless...